# Capturar el id de un tabla con js y usarlo para crear otra trabla en una ventana modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

hola espero me puedan ayudar, tengo una tabla donde de muestran los registros de reclamos por mercaderia de los cliente y el estado de cada uno, cuando selecciono uno de los registros a traves de un boton se abre una ventana modal con los datos del reclamo, el boton captura el id del registo con js y por medio de este datos paso la informacion a ajax que se comunica con el controlador y este a su vez con el modelo para devolver los datos y llenar los campos del formulario, al final del formulario tengo un tabla donde esta el detalle de la mercaderia que reclama el cliente, el problema es que no logro encontrar las forma de de pasarle el id a ajax y que lo devuelva para construir la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**este es el Boton que captura el id**

```
echo '<td><button class="btn btn-info btnEditarUsuario" idUsuario="'.$value["id"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarUsuario"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></td>';
```

**con este codigo traigo los datos del registro para llenar el formulario el cual funciona bien**

```
 $(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEditarReclamoPendiente", function(){

  var idReclamo = $(this).attr("idReclamo");

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("idReclamo", idReclamo);

  $.ajax({

    url:"ajax/reclamos.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta){

      $("#ReclamoEditarHRPendiente").val(respuesta["hr"]);
      $("#ReclamoEditarFechaHRPendiente").val(moment(respuesta["fecha_hr"]).locale("es").format("L"));
      $("#ReclamoEditarCuentaPendiente").val(respuesta["cuenta"]);
      $("#TxtReclamoEditarPendiente").val(respuesta["texto_reclamo"]);
      $("#TipoReclamoEditarReclamo").val(respuesta["tipo"]);
      $("#ReclamoEditaridPendiente").val(respuesta["id"]);
      $("#ReclamoEditarFechaPendiente").val(moment(respuesta["fecha"]).locale("es").format("L h:mm A"));

    }

  });

})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**la tabla de abajo es la que no puedo activar intente de esta forma sin exito**

```
    $(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEditarReclamoPendiente", function() {

    var idReclamo = $(this).attr("idReclamo");

  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("idReclamo", idReclamo);

  console.log("idReclamo", idReclamo);

    $.ajax({

    url:"ajax/datatable-detalle.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    success: function(respuesta){

 $(".tablaDetalle").DataTable(respuesta);




    }

  });
```

**aca esta el codigo de ajax**

```
    <?php


require_once "../controladores/reclamos.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/reclamos.modelo.php";

class TablaDetalle{

    public $idReclamo

    public function mostrarTablaDetalle(){


          $item = "id_reclamo";
          $valor = $this->idReclamo;

          var_dump($valor);


          $reclamos = ControladorReclamos::ctrMostrarDetalle($item, $valor);

$datosJson = '{
  "data": [';

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($reclamos); $i++){ 

    $datosJson.='[
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["id"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["id_reclamo"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["bulto"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["display"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["unidad"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["producto"].'"
    ],';
  }

  $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0,-1);

  $datosJson.= '] 

}';

        echo $datosJson;

    }

}

if(isset($_POST["idReclamo"])){

$activarDetalle = new TablaDetalle();
$activarDetalle -> idReclamo = $_POST["idReclamo"];
$activarDetalle -> mostrarTablaDetalle();
```

**se que funciona el ajax porque al emilinar la varible y solicitar la tabla colocando en el paremetro valor 1 por ejemplo, y sin enviar la variable post (que creo es lo que esta mal y no se como enviar) si responde de forma correcta el controlador y el modelo, construyendo la tabla con los datos json.
ejemplo**

**archivo js**

```
    $.ajax({

  url: "ajax/datatable-detalle.ajax.php",

  success:function(respuesta){

    console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

  }
})

    $('.tablaDetalle').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "ajax/datatable-detalle.ajax.php"
    } );
```

**archivo ajax**

```
    <?php

require_once "../controladores/reclamos.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/reclamos.modelo.php";


class TablaDetalle{


/*=============================================
MOSTARR TABLA DETALLE
=============================================*/


  public function mostrarTablaDetalle(){


      $item = "id_reclamo";
          $valor = 1;

          $reclamos = ControladorReclamos::ctrMostrarDetalle($item, $valor);


          $datosJson = '{
  "data": [';

  for($i = 0; $i < count($reclamos); $i++){

    $datosJson .='[
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["id"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["id_reclamo"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["bulto"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["display"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["unidad"].'",
      "'.$reclamos[$i]["producto"].'"
    ],';
  }

  $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0,-1);

$datosJson.= '] 

}';

echo $datosJson;




  }
}

/*=============================================
ACTIVAR TABLA DETALLE
=============================================*/
$activarDetalle = new TablaDetalle();
$activarDetalle -> mostrarTablaDetalle();
```

**resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**es lo que deceo conseguir pero de forma dinamica que cada detalle de reclamo me muestre el detalle de mercaderia correspondiente**

Answer (score 0):

Verifica la variable en javascript antes de enviarla, tal vez no está enviando el id.

Tip: 
Puedes generar un json con una función de php, así te evitas la construcción con el foreach.

$objetoClase = new ObjetoClase();

$json = json_encode($objetoClase);

Comment: si he verificado con console.log y esta bien lo que creo que estoy haciendo mal es la sintaxis para ir al archivo ajax y que reciba esa variable POST, ` $(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEditarReclamoPendiente", function(){
var idReclamo = $(this).attr("idReclamo");
console.log("idReclamo", idReclamo);
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("idReclamo", idReclamo);
$('.tablaDetalle').DataTable( {
"destroy": true,
"ajax": {
"url": "ajax/datatable-detalle.ajax.php",
"type": "POST",
"data": "datos"
},
} );
} );`